# Vector-valued Holomorphic Functions. Definition.

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-spaces

[image]

In what sense is the existence of the limit?  $\left\|\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}\right\|_{X}<\infty?$

[image]
What is convergence in the norm topology?

Comment: Do you know what topology is?

Comment: The topology is formed by the open balls of $\left\{B(x,r):x\in X,\, r\geq 0\right\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existence of a limit is a lot more than simply "being less than $\infty$". Saying that some limit has magnitude $< \infty$ already implies that we can assign a value to that limit, which may or may not be true. For a simple example, consider $f\colon \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R},\ f(x) = x/|x|$. Then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$ **doesn't exist** at all, so it's nonsensical to even ask if $\left|\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)\right|<\infty$. Specifically, the limit doesn't exist because if we approach $0$ from the left and the right, we get different results.

For a holomorphic function, the existence is super important because it gives holomorphic functions all their cool properties. The fact that the limit is the same no matter from which direction on the complex plane $h\to 0$ is **extremely strong** and goes far beyond just making sure the limit is finite.

The correct definition for existence of a limit, in a general metric space setting which we'll need for the second part of your question, is: let $(X,d), (Y,d')$ be metric spaces, $\Omega\subseteq X$, and $f\colon \Omega\setminus \{c\} \to X$ be a function. Then we say that $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)$ **exists** and equals $L$ if and only if for all $\varepsilon >0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $f(B(c;\delta)\setminus \{c\}) \subseteq B(L;\varepsilon)$. (Here, $B(p;r)= \{q \in X \mid d(q,p) < r\}$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $p$). Note that to measure the first ball, we use the metric $d$, while for the second we use $d'$, since it's in the metric space $(Y,d')$.

Any time you want to compute a limit, you have to specify the metric space in which you want the computation to take place (we could work with general topological spaces, but limits might not be unique in such a general setting which is an unnecessary complication). In the second excerpt that you sent, we're dealing with a function $f\colon U\to E$, where $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ so inherits its metric, and $E$ is a Banach space. Recalling our definitions, a Banach space is a complete normed vector space, so we have a notion of "size" for any vector $v \in E$. The way we get a metric from this is by setting $d(x,y)= \|x-y\|_E$. Since $E$ is now *also* a metric space, we can compute limits in it using the above definition. When the textbook author says "convergence in the norm topology," the mean convergence measured with metric induced by the norm on the Banach space, i.e. the one I just described.

Comment: I read everything and I thank you. I think I understood with what I read that for each $a\in G\subset\mathbb{C},\, \lim_{t\to a}\frac{f(t)-f(a)}{t-a}$ exists in $X$ Banach space if and only if for each $a\in G,\exists v\in X$ such that $\lim_{t\to a}\frac{f(t)-f(a)}{t-a}=v$ and this is equivalent $\lim_{t\to a}\left\|\frac{f(t)-f(a)}{t-a}-v\right\|_{X}=0$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.